# How do you view the details of a submitted task with IPython Parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

I'm submitting tasks using a Load Balanced View.

I would like to be able to connect from a different client and view the remaining tasks by the function and parameters that were submitted.

Forexample:

```
def someFunc(parm1, parm2):
    return parm1 + parm2

lbv = client.load_balanced_view()
async_results = []
for parm1 in [0,1,2]:
    for parm2 in [0,1,2]:
        ar = lbv.apply_async(someFunc, parm1, parm2)
        async_results.append(ar)
```

From the client I submitted this from I can figure out which result went with which function call based on their order in the async_results array.

What I would like to know is how can I figure out the function and parameters associated with a msg_id if I am retrieving the results from a different client using the queue_status or history commands to get msg_id's and the client.get_result command to retrieve the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are pickled, and stored in the 'buffers' in the hub's database. If you want to look at them, you have to fetch those buffers from the database, and unpack them.

Assuming you have a list of msg_ids, here is a way that you can reconstruct the f, args, and kwargs for all of those requests:

```
# msg_ids is a list of msg_id, however you decide to get that
from IPython.zmq.serialize import unpack_apply_message

# load the buffers from the hub's database:
query = rc.db_query({'msg_id' : {'$in' : msg_ids } }, keys=['msg_id', 'buffers'])
# query is now a list of dicts with two keys - msg_id and buffers

# now we can generate a dict by msg_id of the original function, args, and kwargs:
requests = {}
for q in query:
    msg_id = 
    f, args, kwargs = unpack_apply_message(q['buffers'])
    requests[q['msg_id']] = (f, args, kwargs)
```

From this, you should be able to associate tasks based on their function and args.

One Caveat: since f has been through pickling, often the comparison `f is original_f` will be False, so you have to do looser comparisons, such as `f.__module__ + f.__name__` or similar.

For a bit more detail, [here is an example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4313799/) that generates some requests,
then reconstructs and associates them based on the function and arguments having some prior knowledge of what the original requests may have looked like.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. There are several places in the IPython docs where they talk about collaborative cluster use, but it doesn't seem very straight forward connecting to a cluster and figuring out what is going on.